# How to change thumbnail default size?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have added the following code in my `functions.php`

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );  
set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150);
```

My posts display with a thumbnail with the 150x150 dimensions. However, I'd like to change the size. When I change the 150 by 150 in the `set_post_thumbnail_size` to 200 or any other number, it doesn't actually change the size of my thumbnails. I tried going into media settings and change the size there. In the media settings I can shrink the size, but if I try to change it to 200 or 300 it doesn't actually have any impact.

Any idea how I can modify it?

Comment: Hmm.. maybe you could look into [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

Comment: you need define in size measure, what do you mean _"it doesn't actually change the size"_ ?

Comment: i think that you have to **regenerate** your thumbnails with this kind of plugins: [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) or/and [Force Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/).

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Something wrong in your call I guess. Please take a look at here https://nerodev.com/creating-post-thumbnails-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using is correct. The problem is that you are looking at `thumbnail`s that have already been created. As @Loius mentioned you will need to use [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to see the effect. Why core has not implemented this is beyond me.

Comment: Because it's a non-trivial operation, core has no way of knowing if the thumbnail size has changed, and would have to check each image individually to test if they need regenerating. That's not really an issue when you have a plugin you can tell to start bulk processing thumbnails

Comment: I have to say that most devs download it, it’s practically a requirement for the featured image “feature”. In fact it could work in tandem with the other custom image “features” (custom header etc.) if there were concern. I’m thinking of so many reasons it makes sense to include it.

Answer (score 0):

**Define your own image sizes**

If you need your post thumbnail 50px by 50px without cropping the image as well without distorting it. Here is the solution. These all definitions should define in `functions.php` file.

`set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50 );` // 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall, resize mode

As well as you can crop the image as you want. Here is an example for cropping.

`set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50, array( 'top', 'left') );` // 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall, crop from the top left corner

In the array have pass the where to crop. This will crop the image starting from top left corner. If you need to crop the image from the center, just pass `array( 'center', 'center' )` . This will crop the image from the center.

Not only these. You can define your own thumbnail name and define the sizes. Assume I need to create a thumbnail image for books category. Therefore I need an image 200px width and height should be auto . Lets see how to do this.

`add_image_size( 'books', 200, 9999 );` //200 pixels wide (and unlimited height)

This will resize the book category image to 200px width and auto height.

You can call this image

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'books' ); ?>
```

In a proper way you can call this image,

```
<?php
if(has_post_thumbnail( 'books' )) {
the_post_thumbnail( 'books' );
}
?>
```

This will load the image where you define the code and it will be 200px wide and height is relative to the width.

Assume you’re wanting to add this Featured Images for books and all posts except other all custom post types. How to do this. See the code below. It’ll enable the Featured Image for all the posts and custom post type called books only.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'books' ) );
```

Source from [nerodev](https://nerodev.com/creating-post-thumbnails-in-wordpress/)